# How can I insert blank rows every 3 existing rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, addition, each, blank-line

How can I insert blank rows every 3 existing rows in a data frame?
After a web scraping process I get a dataframe with the information I need, however the final excel format requires that I add a blank row every 3 rows. I have searched the web for help but have not found a solution yet.

With hypothetical data, the structure of my data frame is as follows:

```r
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = rep(1:3,c(3,3,3)),  
  "X" = as.character(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")), 
  "Y" = seq(1,18, by=2)
  )

mi_df
  ID X  Y
1  1 a  1
2  1 a  3
3  1 a  5
4  2 b  7
5  2 b  9
6  2 b 11
7  3 c 13
8  3 c 15
9  3 c 17
```

The result I hope for is something like this

```r
   ID X  Y
1   1 a  1
2   1 a  3
3   1 a  5
4
5   2 b  7
6   2 b  9
7   2 b 11
8
9   3 c 13
10  3 c 15
11  3 c 17
```

Comment: Do you want to add a row _after each ID_? (which happens to be every third row in the example)

Comment: The first thing to do is fix that absurd rule in Excel.  There is no excuse for designing a spreadsheet with blank rows.  I know, I know: some PHB insists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indices of a data frame contain `NA`, then the output will have `NA` rows. So my goal is to create a vector like `1 2 3 NA 4 5 6 NA ...` and set it as the indices of `mi_df`.

```
cut <- rep(1:(nrow(mi_df)/3), each = 3)
mi_df[sapply(split(1:nrow(mi_df), cut), c, NA), ]

#      ID    X  Y
# 1     1    a  1
# 2     1    a  3
# 3     1    a  5
# NA   NA <NA> NA
# 4     2    b  7
# 5     2    b  9
# 6     2    b 11
# NA.1 NA <NA> NA
# 7     3    c 13
# 8     3    c 15
# 9     3    c 17
# NA.2 NA <NA> NA
```

---

If `nrow(mi_df)` is not a multiple of 3, then the following is a general solution:

```
# Version 1
cut <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(mi_df)/3), each = 3, len = nrow(mi_df))
mi_df[Reduce(c, lapply(split(1:nrow(mi_df), cut), c, NA)), ]

# Version 2
cut <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(mi_df)/3), each = 3, len = nrow(mi_df))
mi_df[Reduce(function(x, y) c(x, NA, y), split(1:nrow(mi_df), cut)), ]
```

---

Don't mind the `NA` in the output because some functions which write data to an excel file have an optional argument controls if `NA` values are converted to strings or be empty. E.g.

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(df, "test.xlsx", keepNA = FALSE) # defaults to FALSE
```

[image]

Comment: Great Darren, definitely a very useful option, thanks a lot.

Comment: Great Darren, definitely a very useful option. However the NA option that worked for me was showNA = FALSE

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is somewhat different from all the other answers:  don't make a mess of your dataset inside `R` .  Use the existing packages to write to designated rows in an Excel workbook.  For example, with the package `xlConnect`,  the method `writeWorksheet` (called from `writeWorksheetToFile` ) includes these arguments:

> object The workbook to write to data Data to write
>   sheet The name or index of the sheet to write to
>   startRow Index of the first row to write to. The default is startRow = 1.
>   startCol Index of the first column to write to. The default is startCol = 1.

So if you simply set up a loop that writes 3 rows of your data file at a time, then moves the row index down by 4 and writes the next 3 rows, etc., you're all set.

Comment: I tried using the xlConnect package but I had problems binding to Java with the xlsx package, I am a little new to this, hope to do it in the future, thanks Carl.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp <- split(mi_df, rep(1:(nrow(mi_df) / 3), each = 3))
# or split(mi_df, ggplot2::cut_width(seq_len(nrow(mi_df)), 3, center = 2))
do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, function(x) { x[4, ] <- NA; x }))
```

> ```
>       ID    X  Y
> 1.1    1    a  1
> 1.2    1    a  3
> 1.3    1    a  5
> 1.4   NA <NA> NA
> 2.4    2    b  7
> 2.5    2    b  9
> 2.6    2    b 11
> 2.4.1 NA <NA> NA
> 3.7    3    c 13
> 3.8    3    c 15
> 3.9    3    c 17
> 3.4   NA <NA> NA
> ```

You can make empty rows like you show by assigning an empty character vector (`""`) instead of `NA`, but this will convert your columns to character, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: You could also use out-of-bounds indexing: `do.call(rbind, by(mi_df, rep(1:(nrow(mi_df) / 3), each = 3), `[`, 1:4, ))`. Of course the inline backticks around `[` got messed up - I neeeever learn how to do ;) Anyway, I suspect OP wants empty space instead of `NA` (for nice print formatting).

Comment: @Henrik actually `NA` in the output do not matter because some functions which write data to an excel file have an optional argument controlling that `NA` values are converted to strings or be empty. E.g. `openxlsx::write.xlsx(..., keepNA = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method.
Splits into list by ID, adds empty row, then binds list back into data frame.

```
mi_df2 <- do.call(rbind,Map(rbind,split(mi_df,mi_df$ID),rep("",3)))
rownames(mi_df2) <- NULL
```